# DB2 indexing setup

Tags: db2

I am looking through some table source code, and I'm not sure how indexes work. Here is the example I see.

```
CREATE INDEX INDEXNAME ON AWARD ( AWARD_ID, CUST_ID );
```

I don't understand what the parameter values mean. Is the index for each individual column, or is it combined together to become an index.

Comment: it's an index that happens to index two fields, award_id and cust_id. That's all.

Comment: appreciated, thank you. could you recommend a good db2 resource to reference? the IBM site is god awful to read and the examples aren't explained very well.

Comment: for this sort of thing, it's just plain standard sql.

Comment: This is called a composite key.  The key is *composed* of more than one field.

Answer (score 2):

It's an index that contains two fields.  Indexes in general are used for Selection, Joining, Grouping and/or Ordering.

The key thing to realize is that a multi column index is useful from left to right.

For selection, such an index would be quite useful if you had a where clause that looked like

```
WHERE AWARD_ID = 123 AND CUST_ID = 456
```

If would also be helpful for

```
WHERE AWARD_ID = 123
```

But probably not (directly) helpful for

```
WHERE CUST_ID = 456
```

Since the leftmost column of the index (AWARD_ID) is not referenced.

Joining works in a similar manner.

```
--index useful
FROM TBLA JOIN AWARD USING (AWARD_ID,CUST_ID)
 or
FROM TBLA JOIN AWARD USING (AWARD_ID)
--index NOT useful
FROM TBLA JOIN AWARD USING (CUST_ID)
```

as do ordering and grouping.

If you happen to be using DB2 for IBM i, the following paper is an awesome resource:

http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/stg_ast_sys_wp_db2_i_indexing_methods_strategies

If DB2 LUW, the parts about bitmap indexs probably apply, but ignore the information about EVI indexes.  Also look at the planning and performance sub-sections Indexes section in the DB2 LUW infocenter
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc-gentopic8.html